# jquery button event function to target button by ID

Tags: jquery, function, events, siblings

I have a page full of divs that contain 1 button each which submit to do a certain function successfully.

However I am currently trying to isolate the buttons by an ID and trigger the addition of a class and message to 2 spots within the div (input value & the #msgsC).

However, the event is not triggering at all. And I think I may be missing something. How can I get it to change/add the class and message to only the sibling input tag and #msgsC of the particular button that is clicked (AND not to all of the inputs in all the divs on the page simultaneously)?

```
<form id="Hello" target="somePlace" action="#" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="os0">
                    <option value="item1">item1</option>
                    <option value="item2">item2</option>
                    <option value="item3">item3</option>
                    <option value="item1">item4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Send My URL"/>Send My URL
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="http://" name="os1" id="os1" maxlength="200"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button alt="Click the button" id="purchase1" name="submit" class="btn" type="image">Add To Cart</button>
</form>




$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#purchase1, #purchase2, #purchase3').on('click', 'button', function (e) {
        var urlGo = new Array(url1, url2, url3);

        for (var x = 0; x < urlGo.length; x++) {

            if (!/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(urlGo[x].val())) {
                $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").addClass("errorAlert");
                $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val(emptyerror);
                $(this).siblings("#msgsC").addClass("text-error");
                $(this).siblings("#msgsC").html(htmlEmpty);

            } //end of if
        } //end of for
    }); // end of purchase button function
}); // end document ready
```

Comment: there are no elements with class `purchase1`, 2 or 3

Comment: `#` denotes an ID, `.` denotes a class.  Change your selector to `$('#purchase1, #purchase2, #purchase3')` and remove `'button'` as they *are* buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` refers to a class, `#` to an id.

`.purchase` selects element of class purchase, `#purchase` selects element of id purchase.

Use

```
$('#purchase1, #purchase2, #purchase3').on(...
```

since purchase1, purchase2, purchase3 are ids.

And if you are only interested on clicks and these elements are loaded once and not replaced or removed, you may also use,

```
$('#purchase1, #purchase2, #purchase3').click(function(){..
```

You may also give a common class to them, "purchase".

And then use,

```
$('.purchase').click(function(){  ....});
```

But remember, id's are unique.

Comment: Yes thank you. I have been doing a lot of changes in hopes to find out what the problem is. I had only just realized that I may have accidentally left those as classes instead of ids (doh!). So I came back to correct it. However, i changed the classes to IDs and it still is not working. I saw somewhere that the button tag will only respond to the on('click', 'button' function(){});  but I am having no luck with that as well. I will keep trying.

Comment: I am able to get the classes changed and the input and span tags now reflect the proper messages. But I would like the buttons to effect each div's text input and #msgsC span tags depending on which button is pressed. For instance, pressing button 2 should only effect div 2's span and input. However, right now, all three divs' elements are responding. I am wrapping my mind around how the button event may help with that. Thanks for your input It has gotten me in the right direction.

Comment: No more help is needed on this particular snippet. As a matter of fact, I did figure it out and would love to post the new code as an answer to my question so that anyone else, who finds it useful, can use. The only other thing I need would be to know how to condense it into a less bulky version. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This current post was to find help with getting element IDs dynamically and serving them error messages. That has now been resolved so I had to create a new post for the condensing question. here is the newer post with the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658872/making-dynamic-jquery-switch-statement-less-bulky