# Making Dynamic JQuery Switch Statement Less Bulky

Tags: jquery, forms, button, switch-statement

I have a php page with several forms on it. About 9 in total but my example will only reflect 4 for the sake of brevity. I have finally gotten the code to successfully find element ids depending on which button was click on it's form and validates if the url has been added correctly to the form, if not it will show an error message and highlight the input (while also leaving a supporting error message at the bottom of the div in the span tag. The code works excellently and anyone is welcomed to use it, if needed. I would just need help in condensing it. Is there anyway to make the Switch less bulky?

===EXAMPLE FORM HTML (there are several of these on one page) ===

```
<div class="thumbnail">

    <form id="buyMe" action="#" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="none" value="#">
            <input type="hidden" name="#">
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr><td><select id="select" name="os0">
                    <option value="opt1">option 1</option>
                    <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
                    <option value="opt4">Option 4</option>
                </select> 
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="hidden" id="on1" name="on1" value="This Title">This One Title</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input id="os1" type="text" value="http://" name="urlText" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
        </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="something" value="something">
            <button alt="tryThis" id="purchase1" name="submit" class="btn" type="image">Try This</button>
            <img alt="" border="0" src="pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
    <span id="msgsText1">Error Msgs appear here</span>
</div>
```

=== JQuery SWITCH/CASE ==

```
    //BEGINNING OF SWITCH CODE
    emptyerror2 = "Please enter a valid URL";
    htmlEmpty = "Please use the proper URL format";
    success2 = "Added to cart successfully!";

$(' :button').click(function (e) {
    var btns = ["purchase1", "purchase2", "purchase3", "purchase4"];
    for (var i = 0, ii = btns.length; i < ii; i++) {
        var aTc = btns[i];
        var whatSpan = $(this).parent('#buyMe').nextAll('span').eq(0).attr('id');
        var msgSpan = $('#'+ whatSpan);
        var whoseInput = $(this).siblings('#myTable').find(':input').eq(2).attr('id');
        var myInput = $('#'+ whoseInput);
        if ((e.target || e.srcElement).id == aTc) {
            switch (aTc) {
                case 'purchase1':
                            if (!/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(myInput.val())) {
                            myInput.addClass("errorAlert");
                            myInput.val(emptyerror2);
                            msgSpan.addClass("text-error");
                            msgSpan.html(htmlEmpty);
                            return false;
                            } else {
                            myInput.removeClass("errorAlert");
                            msgSpan.removeClass("text-error");
                            msgSpan.addClass("text-success");
                            msgSpan.html(success2);
                            return true;
                            } // end of if else
                        break;
                case 'purchase2':
                            if (!/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(myInput.val())) {
                            myInput.addClass("errorAlert");
                            myInput.val(emptyerror2);
                            msgSpan.addClass("text-error");
                            msgSpan.html(htmlEmpty);
                            return false;
                            } else {
                            myInput.removeClass("errorAlert");
                            msgSpan.removeClass("text-error");
                            msgSpan.addClass("text-success");
                            msgSpan.html(success2);
                            return true;
                            } // end of if else
                        break;
                case 'purchase3':
                            if (!/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(myInput.val())) {
                            myInput.addClass("errorAlert");
                            myInput.val(emptyerror2);
                            msgSpan.addClass("text-error");
                            msgSpan.html(htmlEmpty);
                            return false;
                            } else {
                            myInput.removeClass("errorAlert");
                            msgSpan.removeClass("text-error");
                            msgSpan.addClass("text-success");
                            msgSpan.html(success2);
                            return true;
                            } // end of if else
                        break;
                case 'purchase4':
    if (!/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(myInput.val())) {
                            myInput.addClass("errorAlert");
                            myInput.val(emptyerror2);
                            msgSpan.addClass("text-error");
                            msgSpan.html(htmlEmpty);
                            return false;
                            } else {
                            myInput.removeClass("errorAlert");
                            msgSpan.removeClass("text-error");
                            msgSpan.addClass("text-success");
                            msgSpan.html(success2);
                            return true;
                            } // end of if else
                        break;
               }//end of switch
            } //end of if
        } // end of for loop
    }); //end of button event code
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the cases? They seem to be all doing the same thing...

Comment: And if there's no difference between the cases then you can get rid of the switch entirely

Comment: As mentioned earlier in the original post, There are several forms with submit buttons (ie: purchase1, purchase2, purchase3, purchase4) I only posted 1 form for the sake of brevity. I need the cases in order to keep track of which button is clicked because the variables such as myInput and msgSpan are dynamic and change depending on which submit button is clicked. for instance, clicking on purchase3 submit button will then cause the myInput id to change to os3 and msgSpan will now be msgsText3. Although, I am seeing that Tarnation is right, I may not even need the switch statement at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure you need the loop or the switch at all. The switch statements all seem identical. The spans and inputs all seem to be determined by the execution context. What about just:

```
  $(' :button').click(function (e) {
        var whatSpan = $(this).parent('#buyMe').nextAll('span').eq(0).attr('id');
        var msgSpan = $('#'+ whatSpan);
        var whoseInput = $(this).siblings('#myTable').find(':input').eq(2).attr('id');
        var myInput = $('#'+ whoseInput);
        if (!/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(myInput.val())) {
                            myInput.addClass("errorAlert");
                            myInput.val(emptyerror2);
                            msgSpan.addClass("text-error");
                            msgSpan.html(htmlEmpty);
                            return false;
                            } else {
                            myInput.removeClass("errorAlert");
                            msgSpan.removeClass("text-error");
                            msgSpan.addClass("text-success");
                            msgSpan.html(success2);
                            return true;
                            }
```

If you are worried about 'stray' click events ( have other buttons on the page ), give these four a unique class. Otherwise, it seems like you are just checking if the button is one of four ( where you can know it is ) and performing the same validation no matter which. Of course, I could be missing something!

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion makes sense. I will test it out, when I am next able, and let you know.

Comment: Thank you. This worked well and cleaned up the bulky redundancies. I think your code only needed a });  at the end to close the button click function. THANKS AGAIN.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to make the code more compact.

One is to use an object to do the switching:

```
var switcher = { 'purchase1': purchase1, ... };
...
switcher[aTc]();
```

That allows you to spread the code over several functions. Next, it seems that the code in each switch statement looks very similar. So you could use this pattern:

```
var data = { msgSpan: $('#'+ whatSpan), ... };
var validators = { 'purchase1': function(text) {
    return !/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(text); }
    ...
};
var validator = validators[aTc];
updateUI(data, validator(myInput.val()));
```

The function `updateUI` is then the same for every case.

This approach allows you to split the huge function into many small building blocks that you can test independently. You can also give meaningful names to each piece which works as a reliable source of documentation.

Or you can attach the validator to the element using [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) when you create it and use it like so:

```
var validator = myInput.data('validator');
updateUI(data, validator(myInput.val()));
```